# Asp.net SignalR not working while deployed in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, azure-redis-cache, signalr-backplane

I am using Asp.Net signal for sending user specific notification. Everything working fine in debug mode using visual studio but the same breaks while deployed to Azure.

I am using redis cache.

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(NotifSystem.Web.Startup))]
namespace NotifSystem.Web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseStackExchangeRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration("mySrver:6380,password=password,ssl=True", "YourServer"));
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

My Hub Class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using NotificationHub.Models.Hubs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NotificationHub.Hubs
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserHubModels> Users =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserHubModels>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        //private NotifEntities context = new NotifEntities();

    //Logged Use Call
    public void GetNotification()
    {
        try
        {
            string loggedUser = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            //Get TotalNotification
            //string totalNotif = LoadNotifData(loggedUser);

            //Send To
            UserHubModels receiver;
            if (Users.TryGetValue(loggedUser, out receiver))
            {
                var cid = receiver.ConnectionIds.FirstOrDefault();
                var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
                context.Clients.Client(cid).broadcaastNotif();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    //Specific User Call
    public void SendNotification(string SentTo,string Notification)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get TotalNotification
            //string totalNotif = LoadNotifData(SentTo);

            //Send To
            UserHubModels receiver;
            if (Users.TryGetValue(SentTo, out receiver))
            {
                var cid = receiver.ConnectionIds.FirstOrDefault();
                var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
                context.Clients.Client(cid).broadcaastNotif(Notification);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    private string LoadNotifData(string userId)
    {
        return userId;
        int total = 0;
        //var query = (from t in context.Notifications
        //             where t.SentTo == userId
        //             select t)
        //            .ToList();
        total = 6;
        return total.ToString();
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {

        string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        var user = Users.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new UserHubModels
        {
            UserName = userName,
            ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
        });

        lock (user.ConnectionIds)
        {
            user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);
            if (user.ConnectionIds.Count == 1)
            {
                Clients.Others.userConnected(userName);
            }
        }

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        UserHubModels user;
        Users.TryGetValue(userName, out user);

        if (user != null)
        {
            lock (user.ConnectionIds)
            {
                user.ConnectionIds.RemoveWhere(cid => cid.Equals(connectionId));
                if (!user.ConnectionIds.Any())
                {
                    UserHubModels removedUser;
                    Users.TryRemove(userName, out removedUser);
                    Clients.Others.userDisconnected(userName);
                }
            }
        }

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

}

Javascript Code:

```
var hub = $.connection.notificationHub;
hub.client.broadcaastNotif = function (notification) {
    setTotalNotification(notification)
};
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
        console.log("Connected!");
        hub.server.getNotification();
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("Could not Connect!");
    }); 
 });

function setTotalNotification(notification) {
    if (notification) {
        GetUnreadNotificationCount();
        $('#m_topbar_notification_icon .m-nav__link-icon').addClass('m-animate-shake');
        $('#m_topbar_notification_icon .m-nav__link-badge').addClass('m-animate-blink');
    }
    else {
        $('#m_topbar_notification_icon .m-nav__link-icon').removeClass('m-animate-shake');
        $('#m_topbar_notification_icon .m-nav__link-badge').removeClass('m-animate-blink');
    }
}
```

I have enabled Websocket for that particular App Service.

Cross user notification sending is not successful it only works if the logged in user sends notification to himself only.

Update:

I checked that while a logged in user is doing an activity so that the notification goes to that particular user then it works. Like if a user `user1` sends a notification to `user1` then there is no issue.

Comment: Wanted to follow up to see if you still have an issue with this?

Comment: Hi 
were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

We had same problem with our **Azure SignalR redis BackPlane POC**.

But We tried redis with No SSL port then the Azure SignalR redis BackPlane started working fine. Please check the screenshot Below. Now since the enviorment is self contained we do not need it even HTTPS. We are managing it by Resource Groups and Port Whitelisting.

[image]